# Firebase Cloud Messaging doesn't work on chrome (iOS)

Tags: ios, google-chrome, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've just started testing Firebase for website push notifications. The basic code seems to work perfectly well on many Android-based browsers (Chrome, Firefox...) apps but not those installed on iOS such Chrome on my iPad or iPhone. I couldn't find any information related to this issue. Am I missing something?

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.requestPermission()
.then(function () {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    // TODO(developer): Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM.
    // ...
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
});
```

Comment: does the firebase messaging depends on an installed service worker? iOS doesn't support that yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Chrome on iOS is built on top of the same basic web view as Safari. Since that underlying component doesn't support Web Push, FCM push notifications cannot be delivered to Chrome on iOS.

Comment: Hi @Frank, Im wondering whether there is any way to polyfill this so that its available on iOS Chrome?

Comment: @Frank is there a way to exclude FCM service worker in Safari? because right now it breaks the webpage, and only loads an empty blank page. works fine in all other OS.

Comment: @NadhirFalta you can use `firebase.messaging.isSupported()`

Comment: @AndresSK thank you! that's what I used in my answer below!

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, if you get a blank page on your website on iOS browsers.
just wrap your server worker in an if statement by checking if FCM is supported in that browser `firebase.messaging.isSupported()`

```
if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
    firebase.initializeApp({
        'messagingSenderId': 'your code here'
    });
    ...
}
```